# Informatica Admin Console won't come up

Tags: windows, informatica

I have Informatica 9.5 installed on a Windows 2008 server.  I've recently had to restart the Informatica Service because I was unable to connect to the Informatica Integration Service.  As a result of restarting the Informatica Service, the Admin Console does not come up.  Sometimes, it hangs or I'll get, "The site can't be reached" error.  I've tried going to the site on the server where Informatica application runs, and my pc.  I get the same behavior on both machines.  Also, on the server, I've tried http://localhost:port/administrator.  Same behavior.  Before restarting the Informatica Service, the Admin Console came up.  Is there a service that did not start?

Comment: is the tomcat running properly? You said, it works sometime sometime doesnt ?  ALso make sureyou follow this KB https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/17/334583.aspx

Comment: @KoushikRoy, thanks for responding.  It used to work before restarting the Informatica Service.  I'm new to managing Informatica and was not apart of the initial installation so please bare with me.  How do I find out if tomcat is running properly?

Comment: Also the commands in this https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/17/334583.aspx are for a Linux machine. Is there a similar command I could run for a Windows machine?

Comment: you can get how to set environment variables for infa in documentation. it can be done by right click on my computer > environment variable.